# ffmpeg insert video on top of other video

Tags: ffmpeg, video, batch, video-conversion

I am trying to add video on top of another video but don't know how. I am noob in ffmpeg can any one help.

Code I have tried:

```
ffmpeg -i C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\c\10sec.mp4 
-i C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\1.mp4 
-filter_complex "overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5"  
-codec:a copy C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\output2.mp4
```

If over take old video as both video sizes are the same I don't know how to scale 2nd video down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\c\10sec.mp4" -i "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\1.mp4" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:-1[v2];[0:v][v2]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" -c:v libx264 -c:a copy "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\output2.mp4"
```

As for the batch solution see if this is as expected:

https://youtu.be/B0zv2O-mspI

You copy the following code to notepad and save with the name that you want but with a *.bat extension.

Next you set the path to the folder and to the layout video.

```
@echo off

echo.
set /p "VFolder=Please inform the folder where the videos are: "
set /p "Overlay=Please inform the location of the overlay video: "

pushd "%VFolder%"

for /f "Delims=" %%a in ('dir /b *.mp4 *.avi *.mkv *.mpeg') do ffmpeg -i "%%a" -i "%Overlay%" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=in_w/4:-2[over];[0:v][over]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" -c:v libx264 "1-%%~na.mp4"
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, main video is 10sec.mp4 and  overlay vídeo is 1.mp4, but its overlay 10sec.mp4 ton top of 10sec.mp4 its not picking up 1.mp4 (same video is overlay)... please help ... thx

Comment: please try again with the edits I made...

Comment: Thx Worked ;) ...

Comment: Can you help in one more thing how can i Kee output file name as 1-n.mp4 same as 2nd file? some thing like %%~na.mp4. I am trying to do this to 200 videos where  10sec.mp4 will remain same and 1.mp4 will change so i need to keep file name as 1-n.mp4. can i do that? making batch file? 200 files are in one folder.

Comment: The new files should be copied to the same folder where the 200 vídoes are except with "1-" in the name?

Comment: no, we can add to another folder also or the same which ever is easy ;)

Comment: Please se the updated answer

Comment: What about the audios, should one of the videos audio be muted?

Comment: Music Nice catch ... i was looking for that to... thx I have a folder full of audio files how can i import redone songs to the video output. if it possible? I was also doing some trying to batch files and managed to make it worked here is my code ---
 for %%a in ("*.mp4") do ffmpeg -i C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\c\10sec.mp4 -i "%%a" -filter_complex "[1:v]scale=500:-1[v1];[0:v][v1]overlay=main_w-overlay_w-5:5" -c:v libx264 -shortest -c:a copy "C:\Users\harin\Desktop\test\1\%%~na-n.mp4"